# Prettier auto-correct javascript "import" statement into an one line but then eslitnt 'max-len' rule breaks

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have eslint setup with Prettier formatter in vscode.

there is this following original line,

```
import MyCustomComponentsIsThis 
   from 'queries/internal/consumer/MyCustomComponentsIsThis';
```

Prettier formatter always makes it into a single line as below

```
import MyCustomComponentsIsThis from 'queries/internal/consumer/MyCustomComponentsIsThis';
```

But this will break the esLint max-len rule so still shows it as error on vscode.
How can i overide prettier to keep this like as above two lines of codes

Comment: maybe this helps https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/352#issuecomment-433006095

Answer (score 0):

Add an ignore pattern to your eslint config to ignore import lines:

```json
      rules: {
        "max-len": [
          "error",
          {
            code: 88,
            comments: 86,
            ignoreUrls: true,
            ignoreTemplateLiterals: true,
            ignorePattern: "^import\\s.+\\sfrom\\s.+;$",
          },
        ],
      },
```